# Flask application that Redirects and Does After Request work for both

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask application that I want to have two routes.  I want to do after request work for both of them and have one start once the other finished.

```
@blueprint_main.route('/route1', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def func1():
   <do a few setup activities to give response>
   return redirect ('/route2')


@blueprint_main.after_request()
def post_func1(response)
   if request.path == '/route1':
       <do the first main activities>
   return response

@blueprint_main.route('/route1', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def func2():
   <do a few setup activities>
   return <some response>


@blueprint_main.after_request()
def post_func2(response)
   if request.path == '/route2':
       <do the last main activities>
   return response
```

However, my application seems to be getting stuck in the `after_request` for `route2`.  Is this expected, and if so, is there a way to force Flask to do the `after_request` work for `func1` before starting the `after_request` work for `func2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge all `after_request` functions to one and switch by route to avoid stuck.

```
@blueprint_main.route('/route1', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def func1():
   <do a few setup activities to give response>
   return redirect ('/route2')

@blueprint_main.route('/route2', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def func2():
   <do a few setup activities>
   return <some response>

def post_func1(response):
    <do function 1>
    return response

def post_func2(response):
    <do function 2>
    return response

@blueprint_main.after_request
def post_func(response)
    if request.endpoint in ["blueprint_main.func1"]:
        response = post_func1(response)
    elif request.endpoint in ["blueprint_main.func2"]:
        response = post_func2(response)
   return response
```

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: Hm, I think it is still not working. It is still going straight to `route2`'s after_request work and skipping the after_request work for `route1`. I think I can rewrite my code to just not redirect, but rather just do all the work in both pieces of after_request, so like 

```
@blueprint_main.after_request
def post_func(response)
    if request.endpoint in ["blueprint_main.func1"]:
        response = post_func1(response)
        response = post_func2(response)
    elif request.endpoint in ["blueprint_main.func2"]:
        response = post_func2(response)
   return response
```

Comment: formatting didn't work, but I'll make it as an answer, I guess.